# Error websocket djangochannelsrestframework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, channel

I did websocket connection by djangochannelsrestframework library, it connects but when I send some message it gets this error below
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO3Yi.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what's exactly wrong if I don't see your code

But in my eyes, it seems like you are passing some data that are not JSON serializable - or maybe passing a `set` instead of `dict`